# VSCode Java Formatter don't linebreak when brackets omitted

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I type an if statement on one line

```java
if (root == null) return null
```

VSCode's formatter is putting a linebreak, turning the above into

```java
if (root == null)
    return null;
```

How do I configure the formatter to leave statements like these on one line? I have gone through all the settings in `java-formatter.xml`and can't find one that sounds like it's talking about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find a setting in `java-formatter.xml`:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.keep_imple_if_on_one_line
```

set it to true and try to re-format your source file.